# Elasticache Redis IAM authentication

Tags: redis, amazon-elasticache

I have a question in regards to authenticating with an IAM role in Elasticache. The Java script AWS provides is great for applications (which I linked below) but does `aws-cli` have a built in command for doing this? I notice that `aws-cli` has `generate-db-auth-token` but nothing for Elasticache Redis. The only way I have found is using code to do this but are there any other ways of doing this? Would appreciate any help. Currently, I create the Auth Token through Java with the following:

```
java -cp target/ElastiCacheIAMAuthGenerator-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar \
  com.amazon.elasticache.IAMAuthTokenGeneratorApp \
  --region us-east-1 \
  --replication-group-id "$replication_group_id" \
  --user-id "$user_id"
```

https://github.com/aws-samples/elasticache-iam-auth-demo-app/tree/main